# Boost Python 'int' to C++ int with overloaded function

Tags: c++, boost-python

I was somewhat surprised when I got this error message.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'Packet' and 'int'
```

What I am trying to do is expose a class through boost python that overloads the `__lshift__` operand to take several different object types - such as int, float, char*, etc. I am exposing the class correctly but when I try something like `packet << 10` I get the aforementioned error.

I understand why this is but I'm not sure exactly how I should go about solving this. I cant exactly have an overload with a boost::python::object because then it couldn't distinguish between `packet << 10` and `packet << 10.5`.

One possible solution is to expose the functions as something other than the `__lshift__`. I could then end up with `packet.saveInt(10)` and `packet.saveFloat(10.5)` but that destroys the syntactic sugar that we all so admire in python.

Another idea I had was that I could create a very thin class around the built-in int types and take that in.

```
struct Int32 {
    Int32(bp::object obj) {
        if (PyInt_Check(obj.get()) {
            value = bp::extract<int>(obj);
        }
        PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_ValueError, obj);
        bp::throw_error_already_set();
    }
    int value;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(intwrapper)
{
        bp::class_<Int32>("Int32", bp::init<bp::object>)
            .def("value", &Int32::value);
}
```

With this I could then do the following. `packet << Int32(10)` and similarly `packet << Float(10.5)`. This is kind of hackish and I hope there is a better way.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation I discovered the problem is that I was trying to pass an int by reference and Python does not support that.

I did my best to keep the syntax sugar but eventually went with exposing the different operator <<() and operator >>() methods as saveInt32(value), saveString(value), loadInt32(), loadString() and so on.